# Como mostrar em while um array com varias coisas

Tags: php

Bom, vou me tentar me explicar a minha dúvida da melhor forma:

```
    <?php
    $steamid = 76561198337627631;
        $prices = file_get_contents('prices.txt');
        $prices = json_decode($prices, true);
        $inv = curl('https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$steamid.'/inventory/json/730/2/');
        $inv = json_decode($inv, true);
        $items = array();
        foreach ($inv['rgInventory'] as $key => $value) {
            $id = $value['classid'].'_'.$value['instanceid'];
            $trade = $inv['rgDescriptions'][$id]['tradable'];
            if(!$trade) continue;
            $name = $inv['rgDescriptions'][$id]['market_hash_name'];
            $price = $prices['response']['items'][$name]['value']*10;
            $img = 'http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/'.$inv['rgDescriptions'][$id]['icon_url'];
            $items[] = array(
                'assetid' => $value['id'],
                'bt_price' => "0.00",
                'img' => $img,
                'name' => $name,
                'price' => $price,
                'reject' => $reject,
                'sa_price' => $price,
                'steamid' => $steamid);
        }


        // curl

function getTemplate($name, $in = null) {
    extract($in);
    ob_start();
    include "template/" . $name;
    $text = ob_get_clean();
    return $text;
}

function curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}


 ?>
```

Tenho o seguinte código, e pretendo dar um echo da minha array items, mostrando todos os parametros da mesma, contudo tem que ser em while porque eu tenho vários itens, como poderei fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: Mas o seu com vários items só vai estar composto no final desse while certo? Porque não `foreach` depois do while e aí já pode imprimir cada parametro de cada item

Comment: Poderia me dar um exemplo por gentileza?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Soponhamos que acaba (depois desse while estar terminado) com estes 2 items:

```
$items[] = array(
    'assetid' => 1,
    'bt_price' => "0.00",
    'img' => '123.jpg',
    'name' => 'item1',
    'price' => '12.00',
    'reject' => 'Sim',
    'sa_price' => '10.00',
    'steamid' => 'steam1'
);
$items[] = array(
    'assetid' => 2,
    'bt_price' => "0.00",
    'img' => '456.jpg',
    'name' => 'item2',
    'price' => '2.00',
    'reject' => 'Não',
    'sa_price' => '1.00',
    'steamid' => 'steam2'
);
```

Depois pode fazer:

**Maneira 1:**

```
foreach($items as $item) {
    echo '<b>Detalhes do item ' .$item['name']. '</b>:<br>';
    echo implode(', ', $item). '<br><br>';
}
```

**Maneira 2** (aqui associamos a chave com o valor):

```
foreach($items as $item) {
    echo '<br><br><b>Detalhes do item ' .$item['name']. '</b>:<br>';
    echo implode(', ', array_map(
        function ($v, $k) { return $k. ':' .$v; }, $item, array_keys($item))
    );
}
```

**Maneira 3** (aqui imprimimos só as chaves/valores que queremos):

```
foreach($items as $item) {
    echo '<br><br><b>imagem do item ' .$item['name']. '</b>:<br>';
    echo 'img: ' .$item['img'];
}
```

Comment: É isso mesmo Miguel, mas no caso de eu querer mostrar apenas por exemplo a img, de cada item como faria? Como mencionaria na array?

Comment: Ha isso é mais simples, eu vou colocar a maneira 3 com esse exemplo

Comment: Certo Obrigado.

Comment: Como coloquei na maneira 3 para aceder à `img` basta `$item['img']`

Comment: Obrigado Miguel pela ajuda era isso mesmo que precisava!